# Generating a list of random permutations of another list

Tags: python, random

So, I'm trying to tackle the TSP with a Genetic Algorithm. To do that I need to create a population pool. What I wan't to accomplish is to create a list of random permutations that will represent a population pool. I'm trying to do this using random.shuffle. Here's my code that should handle that part. Cities is a list of cities and routes is where I want to keep the population pool (a list of N random permutations):

```
for x in range(n):
    random.shuffle(cities)
    routes.append(cities)
```

What happens is that it just appends the same permutation n times. Anybody have any idea about what I might be missing?

Answer (score 3):

`shuffle` modifies the list in-place. you need to add a copy of the list to your `routes`; otherwise a reference to the same list is added which will be in its last shuffled state.

```
for x in range(n):
    random.shuffle(cities)
    routes.append(cities.copy())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
print [random.sample(cities,n) for i in xrange(n)]
```

You can try this.