# Generate permutations of an array

Tags: python, numpy, random, permutation

I want to generate a list (of arbitrary length) of arrays, each a random permutation of array `A`. From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33400584/generating-a-list-of-random-permutations-of-another-list):

```
for x in range(n):
    random.shuffle(A)
    routes.append(A)
```

How to efficiently do this with NumPy?

Comment: I think your method is good enough. Except that `shuffle` works in place, so you have to replace `routes.append(A)` by `routes.append(A.copy())`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example:

```
In [59]: crr
Out[59]: 
array([[0.83704624, 0.42109715, 0.50779425, 0.93753455, 0.11773652,
        0.08751938],
       [0.83704624, 0.42109715, 0.50779425, 0.93753455, 0.11773652,
        0.08751938],
       [0.83704624, 0.42109715, 0.50779425, 0.93753455, 0.11773652,
        0.08751938],
       [0.83704624, 0.42109715, 0.50779425, 0.93753455, 0.11773652,
        0.08751938],
       [0.83704624, 0.42109715, 0.50779425, 0.93753455, 0.11773652,
        0.08751938]])

In [60]: np.random.shuffle(crr[0])

In [61]: crr
Out[61]: 
array([[0.42109715, 0.50779425, 0.93753455, 0.11773652, 0.08751938,
        0.83704624],
       [0.83704624, 0.42109715, 0.50779425, 0.93753455, 0.11773652,
        0.08751938],
       [0.83704624, 0.42109715, 0.50779425, 0.93753455, 0.11773652,
        0.08751938],
       [0.83704624, 0.42109715, 0.50779425, 0.93753455, 0.11773652,
        0.08751938],
       [0.83704624, 0.42109715, 0.50779425, 0.93753455, 0.11773652,
        0.08751938]])
```

As random shuffle is in-place, here we can specify only the first row to be shuffled.  Therefore if you use `np.repeat` or `np.tile` to repeat your A for N times and reshape the resultant into a 2D array like `crr` here, you can do this to reach final goal:

```
In [69]: for v in crr:
    ...:     np.random.shuffle(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `np.random.permutation`?  For example:

```py
A = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
n = 17  # list length
x = [np.random.permutation(A)  for i in range(n)]
```

I don't think it's possible to avoid the procedural aspect of looping over `n` iterations, but as in the code snippet above:

- use `np.random.permutation` to avoid using the `random` package
- use a list comprehension to avoid a multi-line loop

Answer (score 0):

NumPy's [new random number generator](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html) can do this, [`numpy.random.Generator.permuted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.permuted.html) is exactly what you are looking for:

```
def solution(ar, nrows, rng=None):
    rng = np.random.default_rng(rng)
    # repeat input with nrows
    out = np.asarray(ar)[None].repeat(nrows, axis=0)
    # shuffle each row in-place
    return rng.permuted(out, axis=1, out=out)
```

Test:

```
>>> solution(np.arange(3), 10)
array([[1, 0, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 0],
       [2, 0, 1],
       [1, 2, 0],
       [0, 2, 1],
       [1, 0, 2],
       [1, 2, 0],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [2, 0, 1]])
```